Word maps from $\mathrm{Cl}^{n+1}$ to $G^n$: quasi-injectivity?
Let $G = \mathrm{SL}_n$ (say). Then, for $g$ regular semisimple, the conjugacy class $\mathrm{Cl}(g)$ has dimension $= n^2-n$ as a variety, and so $\mathrm{Cl}(g)^{n+1}$ and $G^n$ have the same dimension. Is it possible to build a word map
$$\mathrm{Cl}(g)^{n+1} \to G^n$$
$$(g_1,\dotsc,g_{n+1})\mapsto (w_1(\vec{g}),w_2(\vec{g}),w_3(\vec{g}),\dotsc)$$
that is almost-injective, that is, such that the preimage of a typical point in the image has a bounded number of distinct elements?
It is possible to answer this question (with "yes") using algebraic geometry, if one accepts a pretty terrible dependence of the bound on $n$. I am more interested in what can be obtained by means of character theory, say, with the objective being a good dependence of the bounds (the bound on the preimage, that is, or the constants implicit in the definition of "typical") on $n$.
(Feel free to consider $\mathrm{Cl}(g)^{d (n+1)}$ and $G^{d n}$ instead of $\mathrm{Cl}(g)^{n+1}$ and $G^n$; the important thing is that the dimensions match.)

Could you explain (possibly in an answer) the proof using algebraic geometry?

@LSpice Sure. First, construct a dominant map. (Here $(g_1,g_2,\dotsc,g_{n+1})\mapsto (g_1 g_2^{-1},\dotsc,g_n g_{n+1}^{-1})$ will do nicely.) The preimage of a typical point (a "generic" point in the classical sense) is $0$-dimensional, and so the number of points on it is bounded by its degree as a variety. Bounding that degree by a quantity independent of the ground field (but not independent of $n$) is not particularly hard.

(That the preimage of a generic point under a dominant map is $0$-dimensional is something that can be found, say, towards the end of Chapter I in Mumford's Red Book; over arbitrary fields, it has to date to Chevalley at the latest.)

About your definition of "almost injective": a constant map satisfies this (the preimage of a generic point has cardinal 0). You probably don't want this.

@YCor Right, I should have added "dominant" (or said "generic in the image").

@YCir Just fixed it.

So if I understand correctly, eventually you want such a dominant map, with a reasonable bound (w.r. to $n$) on the cardinal of the preimage of a generic point?

Exactly (and on the degree of some proper subvariety of the domain containing all the "bad", "non-generic" points, though we've already got a reasonable (= polynomial) bound on that).

I've asked a question (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/469427/when-is-the-intersection-of-cosets-of-a-conjugacy-class-0-dimensional) equivalent to the special case $w_1=g_1 g_2^{-1}$, $w_2 = g_2 g_3^{-1}$, etc.

The pre print by fumagalli and Maroti on the Gowers trick seems relevant. Indeed it might give the result you need, I'd have to check...

@NickGill That's an interesting lead. Gowers's trick has always been something that works for large sets, and Fumagalli-Maroti is no exception. However - maybe something can be got out of a character-based approach (as in section 6 of Fumagalli-Maroti)?

@HAHelfgott The $\delta$ in the exponent of Theorem 1.1 of  Fumagalli-Maroti means that it applies to a class of regular semisimple elements, right? (For $n$ sufficiently large.)

Sure? Not sure why $n$ would have to be large. So?
